Jolt to handle a multilayered Nested JSON to flat JSON
Input:
{
  "HEADER": {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "ITEM": [
      {
        "DATAB": 20231101,
        "DATBI": 20231101,
        "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
        "NET_0": "13.51 ",
        "NET_1": "13.51 ",
        "NET_2": "13.51 ",
        "NET_3": "13.51 ",
        "NET_4": "13.51 ",
        "NET_5": "13.51 ",
        "TOTAL": "11.74 ",
        "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
        "VRKME": "KAR",
        "CONDITION": [
          {
            "STUNR": "010",
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "ZA01",
            "WAERS": "GBP",
            "KPEIN": "1000 ",
            "KMEIN": "CS",
            "KRECH": "C",
            "KBETR": "27920.00 ",
            "KWERT": "27.92 ",
            "TIF_L3": "GROSS REVENUE"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": "015",
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "ZX01",
            "WAERS": "GBP",
            "KPEIN": "1000 ",
            "KMEIN": "CS",
            "KRECH": "C",
            "KBETR": "-14410.00",
            "KWERT": -14.41,
            "TIF_L3": "NOTIONAL PRICE ADJUSTMENT"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": 520,
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "YY21",
            "KPEIN": "0 ",
            "KRECH": "A",
            "KBETR": "-10.00",
            "KWERT": -0.14,
            "TIF_L3": "JOINT BUSINESS INITIATIVES"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": 526,
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "YY27",
            "KPEIN": "0 ",
            "KRECH": "A",
            "KBETR": "-110.00",
            "KWERT": -1.49,
            "TIF_L3": "DATA SHARING"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": 583,
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "YY95",
            "KPEIN": "0 ",
            "KRECH": "A",
            "KBETR": "-10.00",
            "KWERT": -0.14,
            "TIF_L3": "DAMAGED PACKAGING"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DATAB": 20231102,
        "DATBI": 20231129,
        "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
        "NET_0": "13.51 ",
        "NET_1": "13.51 ",
        "NET_2": "13.51 ",
        "NET_3": "13.51 ",
        "NET_4": "13.51 ",
        "NET_5": "13.51 ",
        "TOTAL": "7.24 ",
        "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
        "VRKME": "KAR",
        "CONDITION": [
          {
            "STUNR": "010",
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "ZA01",
            "WAERS": "GBP",
            "KPEIN": "1000 ",
            "KMEIN": "CS",
            "KRECH": "C",
            "KBETR": "27920.00 ",
            "KWERT": "27.92 ",
            "TIF_L3": "GROSS REVENUE"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": "015",
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "ZX01",
            "WAERS": "GBP",
            "KPEIN": "1000 ",
            "KMEIN": "CS",
            "KRECH": "C",
            "KBETR": "-14410.00",
            "KWERT": -14.41,
            "TIF_L3": "NOTIONAL PRICE ADJUSTMENT"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": 520,
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "YY21",
            "KPEIN": "0 ",
            "KRECH": "A",
            "KBETR": "-10.00",
            "KWERT": -0.14,
            "TIF_L3": "JOINT BUSINESS INITIATIVES"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": 526,
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "YY27",
            "KPEIN": "0 ",
            "KRECH": "A",
            "KBETR": "-110.00",
            "KWERT": -1.49,
            "TIF_L3": "DATA SHARING"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": 546,
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "YY44",
            "WAERS": "GBP",
            "KPEIN": "1 ",
            "KMEIN": "CS",
            "KRECH": "C",
            "KBETR": "-4.50",
            "KWERT": "-4.50",
            "TIF_L3": "PRICE-OFF"
          },
          {
            "STUNR": 583,
            "ZAEHK": "001",
            "KSCHL": "YY95",
            "KPEIN": "0 ",
            "KRECH": "A",
            "KBETR": "-10.00",
            "KWERT": -0.14,
            "TIF_L3": "DAMAGED PACKAGING"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Output Expected:
[
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231101,
    "DATBI": 20231101,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "11.74 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": "010",
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "ZA01",
    "WAERS": "GBP",
    "KPEIN": "1000 ",
    "KMEIN": "CS",
    "KRECH": "C",
    "KBETR": "27920.00 ",
    "KWERT": "27.92 ",
    "TIF_L3": "GROSS REVENUE"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231101,
    "DATBI": 20231101,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "11.74 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": "015",
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "ZX01",
    "WAERS": "GBP",
    "KPEIN": "1000 ",
    "KMEIN": "CS",
    "KRECH": "C",
    "KBETR": "-14410.00",
    "KWERT": -14.41,
    "TIF_L3": "NOTIONAL PRICE ADJUSTMENT"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231101,
    "DATBI": 20231101,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "11.74 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": 520,
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "YY21",
    "KPEIN": "0 ",
    "KRECH": "A",
    "KBETR": "-10.00",
    "KWERT": -0.14,
    "TIF_L3": "JOINT BUSINESS INITIATIVES"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231101,
    "DATBI": 20231101,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "11.74 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": 526,
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "YY27",
    "KPEIN": "0 ",
    "KRECH": "A",
    "KBETR": "-110.00",
    "KWERT": -1.49,
    "TIF_L3": "DATA SHARING"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231101,
    "DATBI": 20231101,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "11.74 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": 583,
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "YY95",
    "KPEIN": "0 ",
    "KRECH": "A",
    "KBETR": "-10.00",
    "KWERT": -0.14,
    "TIF_L3": "DAMAGED PACKAGING"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231102,
    "DATBI": 20231129,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "7.24 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": "010",
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "ZA01",
    "WAERS": "GBP",
    "KPEIN": "1000 ",
    "KMEIN": "CS",
    "KRECH": "C",
    "KBETR": "27920.00 ",
    "KWERT": "27.92 ",
    "TIF_L3": "GROSS REVENUE"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231102,
    "DATBI": 20231129,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "7.24 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": "015",
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "ZX01",
    "WAERS": "GBP",
    "KPEIN": "1000 ",
    "KMEIN": "CS",
    "KRECH": "C",
    "KBETR": "-14410.00",
    "KWERT": -14.41,
    "TIF_L3": "NOTIONAL PRICE ADJUSTMENT"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231102,
    "DATBI": 20231129,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "7.24 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": 520,
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "YY21",
    "KPEIN": "0 ",
    "KRECH": "A",
    "KBETR": "-10.00",
    "KWERT": -0.14,
    "TIF_L3": "JOINT BUSINESS INITIATIVES"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231102,
    "DATBI": 20231129,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "7.24 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": 526,
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "YY27",
    "KPEIN": "0 ",
    "KRECH": "A",
    "KBETR": "-110.00",
    "KWERT": -1.49,
    "TIF_L3": "DATA SHARING"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231102,
    "DATBI": 20231129,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "7.24 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": 546,
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "YY44",
    "WAERS": "GBP",
    "KPEIN": "1 ",
    "KMEIN": "CS",
    "KRECH": "C",
    "KBETR": "-4.50",
    "KWERT": "-4.50",
    "TIF_L3": "PRICE-OFF"
  },
  {
    "VKORG": 1501,
    "VTWEG": 10,
    "KUNNR": "0006503254",
    "WAERK": "GBP",
    "DATAB": 20231102,
    "DATBI": 20231129,
    "BASE_PRICE": "27.92 ",
    "NET_0": "13.51 ",
    "NET_1": "13.51 ",
    "NET_2": "13.51 ",
    "NET_3": "13.51 ",
    "NET_4": "13.51 ",
    "NET_5": "13.51 ",
    "TOTAL": "7.24 ",
    "MATNR": "000000000000021424",
    "VRKME": "KAR",
    "STUNR": 583,
    "ZAEHK": "001",
    "KSCHL": "YY95",
    "KPEIN": "0 ",
    "KRECH": "A",
    "KBETR": "-10.00",
    "KWERT": -0.14,
    "TIF_L3": "DAMAGED PACKAGING"
  }
]

I'm trying to write a spec to do the below transformation using jolt transformation. I need to convert the flat json to nested Json
I am having some trouble with converting the flat JSON to Nested JSON. I have looked at examples and didn't get any closer as to what is mentioned above. I need to transform a JSON structure by using a JOLT spec. I use https://jolt-demo.appspot.com to test the following below.

Welcome to SO Jason

You can loop within the CONDITION array's attributes while forming new objects named others1/2 in order to prepare the nested attributes to be dynamically dissipated within the second spec such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "HEADER": {
        "*": "others2.&",
        "ITEM": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&1.others1.&",
            "CONDITION": {
              "*": {
                "*": "&3.&2[&1].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "CONDITION": {
          "*": {
            "@4,others2|@2,others1": { "*": "&4_&3_&1.&" }, // go four and two levels up the tree to grab the values of both of the "others" objects
            "*": "&3_&2_&1.&" //own attributes of the "CONDITION" array
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//get rid of the object keys to have array of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]

